# Taking input of integers until a newline in C/C++

Tags: c++, inputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read integers from a file, line by line in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287121/how-to-read-integers-from-a-file-line-by-line-in-c)

Please anyone can suggest me how to take input of integers until a newline in C++.

Suppose the input stream is

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10, followed by a newline in C++.

Comment: [so] isn't a code writing service. Have you tried anything at all? Are you writing a console application? A Windows form? Maybe start with `cin` and `cout` for some research material.

Comment: this question is a mess, 2 languages and an undefined context where we are suppose to apply your requirements: you can ask about how to read from a console in C or how you read from a stream from a modem in C++ .

Comment: @Cory I have tried much. If u want i can post that also

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık From keyboard

Comment: GetKeyState(key code); gives true/false if the key given is pressed or not. This way, you can check if user pressed "space" and "enter" keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely duplicate of: [How to read groups of integers from a file, line by line in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287121/how-to-read-integers-from-a-file-line-by-line-in-c)

> If you want to deal in a line per line basis:
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>    std::string line;
>    std::vector< std::vector<int> > all_integers;
>    while ( getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
>       std::istringstream is( line );
>       all_integers.push_back( 
>             std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>(is),
>                               std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string the_string;
std::getline(the_stream, the_string);
std::istringstream iss(the_string);
for (int n; iss >> n; )
{
    // do something with n
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat.